# Push error while using javascript & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, push

I did try to find solution by myself and tried to fix it but without any good result. I assume it's probably something easy to fix but I got confused and decided it will be better to ask some more advanced people.

I am trying to do some small easy clicking game using javascript (+YUI library, JSON) and everything was fine the code was working, everything is ok as far as I was just using it as .html and simply opening the index.html by my browser (code in code.js and then index.html calling the script) but then I tried to upgrade it and make it to PHP and still everything looks alright till the momment when I launch my "website" by xampp and go to it by localhost, everything looks good and most of the code/website is working but by some reason one main function instead of working is giving me huge amount of text (It was not showing me everything, but this is what Firebug gave me):

```
<p id="add">function (a){this.push.apply(this,a);return this;}function (d){if(this.length<3){return null;}if(this.length==4&&this[3]==0&&!d){return"transparent"; }var b=[];for(var a=0;a<3;a++){var c=(this[a]-0).toString(16);b.push((c.length==1)?"0"+c:c);}return(d)?b:"#"+b.join("");}function (b){if(this.length!=3){return null; }var a=this.map(function(c){if(c.length==1){c+=c;}return c.toInt(16);});return(b)?a:"rgb("+a+")";}function (){for(var b=0,a=this.length;b</p>
```

**The above code is not mine, it is the output of an "error" I have when I press the button to get credits, I do not have such lines nowhere in my source code and it is cut off at the end because it shows to me this way (firebug gave me whole part as stated above)** 
I don't have such lines in my code and this happens when for example I want to click on a button that will give me credit by clicking onto it (clicking game, You click on the button it will give You credit):

```
function credit() {
    var a = game.credit+=100;
    document.getElementById("add").innerHTML=Fix(a);
}
```

Do I have this problem because I need to use some other function/rewrite my code for PHP ? Or is it because I need to use some push function, or do I have something wrong with my apache? Or it's because of the `document.getElementById` and I should write it differently while using PHP?

Ps: `game.credit` because it's using different function too, and `Fix(a)` because it's using other function to beautify the result. Every other functions are working, only the ones that are responsible for adding the credit are showing me this text.

This is Fix function:

```
function Fix(what){
    var str='';
    what=Math.floor(what);
    what=(what+'').split('').reverse();
    for (var i in what) {
        if (i%3==0 && i>0) str = ','+str;
        str = what[i]+str;
    }
    return str;
}
```

**#Edit**
Ok I just did check it and it's this Fix function causing problem, everything works fine when I do not use it (for example I do: "document.getElementById("add").innerHTML=a;"). So what's wrong with this fix function, can someone help me make it work? This function is changing the numbers in example 1000 to 1,000 and not allowing it to be like 503.0203

Comment: The `function (a){ …` line appears to contain some “compressed”/obfuscated JavaScript. Could you please post the original source code? Otherwise it's very hard to read. (Not to mention that the code is incomplete, it is cut off at the end.)

Comment: it would be helpful if you could post the code of the Fix() function

Comment: @lxg I edited the post and as you mentioned there are a lot of cut off ends. (A lot of missing brackets etc.)

Comment: Thank You for the reply.
As I mentioned before the code "function (a)..." it's not actually a code, I do not have that nowhere in my original code, this long lines shows as an error when I press on my button to get the credits and it is incomplete because it's showing exactly this way, I copied everything that showed up, it's showing to me this way and it's incomplete by itself (I did not cut it off at the end).

Comment: @lxg Edited the first post, wrote the Fix code and whole part of the "error" from firebug.